# How to create an array out of a string and keep spaces & punctuation at the end of each word?

Tags: javascript

Take this string as example:

```
'The strong, fast and gullible cat ran over the street!'
```

I want to create a function that takes this string and creates the following array:

```
['The ','strong, ','fast ','and ','gullible ','cat ','ran ','over ','the ','street!']
```

Observe that I want to keep each puctuation and space **after** each word.

Comment: One option is to replace single spaces with space + some character you know won't appear in the string and then split by that character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regular expression will match what you want: `/[^\s]+\s*/g`;

**EXAPMLE:**

```js
var str = 'The strong, fast and gullible cat ran over the street!';
var result = str.match(/[^\s]+\s*/g);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much <3

Comment: You're welcome! But it will ignore any leading spaces (spaces before the first letter). Is that ok? I assumed there will be none.

Answer (score 2):

You can `split` at word boundaries followed by a word character:

```js
var str = 'The strong, fast and gullible cat ran over the street!';
console.log(str.split(/\b(?=\w)/));
```

Comment: With this sentence `'John's mother'` becomes ["John'", "s ", "mother "]. I would like it to become "John's ". I guess I should tweak the regular expression to match my need. Clearly it is time I dove into the world of  regex. Thank you very much for the time!

Answer (score 1):

As @Summoner commented (while I was modifying my code to do it), if we add some char(s) that we want to use as a delimiter, we can then split on that, rather than the spaces.

```js
var s= 'The strong, fast and gullible cat ran over the street!';
s = s.replace(/\s+/g, " **");
var ary = s.split("**");
console.log(ary);
```

Comment: There will be a problem if there is two spaces after each other.

Answer (score 1):

Gonna toss my solution into the ring as well.   :)

```
var sTestVal = 'The strong, fast and gullible cat ran over the street!';
var regexPattern = /[^ ]+( |$)/g;
var aResult = sTestVal.match(regexPattern)

console.log(aResult);
```

The result is:

```
["The ", "strong, ", "fast ", "and ", "gullible ", "cat ", "ran ", "over ", "the ", "street!"]
```

The regex pattern breaks down like this:

`[^ ]+` - matches one or more non-space characters, and then

`( |$)` - either a space or the end of the string

`g` - it will match all instances of the patternthe end